# How can I remove overflow without losing 100vh height on a section of my CSS page?

Tags: html, css

My instructor wanted me to have a section in my assignment with the height set to viewport, so now I have a big gap between the section and the rest of my content. How do I get rid of the gap and overflow?

```
  <main>
 
     <section id="welcome-section"><h1>Welcome to my Portfolio</h1>
            
     #welcome-section {
    min-height: 100vh;
    font-family: 'Dancing Script', cursive;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 1rem;
    width: 100%;
    }

    #welcome-section h1 {
    font-size: 5rem;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Dancing Script', cursive;
    margin: 30px 30px 40px 30px;
    padding: 20px 0 20px 0;
        color: blueviolet;
   }

    #welcome-section p {
    font-size: 1.5rem
    margin: 2em;
    padding: 1.5em;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set the `min-height` to `max-height`

```
  #welcome-section {
    max-height: 100vh;
    font-family: 'Dancing Script', cursive;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 1rem;
    width: 100%;
    }
```

and dont forget the semicolon here

```
    #welcome-section p {
    font-size: 1.5rem **;**
    margin: 2em;
    padding: 1.5em;
}
```

Comment: Hey Josef, I did want you said and it worked. The thing is that it's not passing this user story thing that the assignment has to pass. (This is what she wants in the assignment, "The height of the welcome section should be equal to the height of the viewport") This is like a quiz it has to pass.